# How to set image size for js tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

I'm working on a js based tooltip right now.
I have found the right coding as a base to work with but now i'm trying to change the image size though i can't find out where to edit this. (it's mainly about a certain width where height would be "automatic")

```js
this.tooltip = function(){  
 /* CONFIG */  
  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;  
  // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
  // you might want to adjust to get the right result  
 /* END CONFIG */  
 $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){             
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = "";           
  $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
   .fadeIn("fast");  
    },
 function(){
  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
 $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
 });   
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
 tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a children of the `tooltip` .Try this css rule `#tooltip img`

**Working example**

```js
this.tooltip = function(){  
 /* CONFIG */  
  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;  
  // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
  // you might want to adjust to get the right result  
 /* END CONFIG */  
 $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){             
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = "";           
  $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
   .fadeIn("fast");  
    },
 function(){
  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
 $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
 });   
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
 tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
}

#tooltip img{
 width:250px;
  height:200px; /* change as your wish */

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

***Another possible method's***

**Inline method**

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img width="100px" height="100px" src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

Direct css with `classname` or `id` with img

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img id="img" src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

***css***

```
#img{
width:250px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add width to image

```
<img width='200' src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>
```

OR

```
<img style='width:200px;' src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the width and image attributes. i have added them on the second image for comparison

Working Code

```js
this.tooltip = function(){  
 /* CONFIG */  
  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;  
  // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
  // you might want to adjust to get the right result  
 /* END CONFIG */  
 $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){             
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = "";           
  $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
   .fadeIn("fast");  
    },
 function(){
  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
 $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
 });   
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
 tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img width='200px' height='300px' src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `img` inside your tooltip, which is inside a `p` tag.
To adjust it, use `#tooltip img` as a selector.

```js
this.tooltip = function(){  
 /* CONFIG */  
  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;  
  // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
  // you might want to adjust to get the right result  
 /* END CONFIG */  
 $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){             
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = "";           
  $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
  $("#tooltip img").css("width", "150px");
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
   .fadeIn("fast");  
    },
 function(){
  this.title = this.t;  
  $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
 $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
  $("#tooltip")
   .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
   .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
 });   
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
 tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>" >TEXTS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it in your CSS:

```
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  display: none;
  max-width: 100px; /* 100px as an example */
}
```